# No link to orphan tag after tag merging in orphan-wikis page

Tags: support, bug, moderator-tools, tag-merge-utility, orphaned-wiki

As a mod I merged [couple of tags](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/13145/176217), but now I can't find the link to nowadays orphaned tag wiki "scroll" in [orphaned wikis page](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/admin/orphan-wikis). What's the reason for that?

Comment: Using [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1231351/orphaned-tag-wikis) I found: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/681948/revisions and https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/681949/revisions - it seems consistent with [the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20210922220118/https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/scroll/info). 
(Of course, this does not answer why you're not seeing the same in the mods' interface.)